# How to handle false negative responses from integrating system

Tags: rest, api, integration

I'm looking to get some discussion regarding how handle the following scenario with integrated apis.

1. You call the 3rd party API to create a resource
2. The API returns a 500 Exception (however, it still creates the resource in their system, but we do not create the resource since the request return an error code)

   - Normally, the API would return a 200 OK and an identifier for the resource.
3. Then the user retries to create the resource
4. The API returns a 400 Exception Resource because it already exists

How would you gracefully handle this? (keep in mind I have to influence on the API developers to fix this)

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you can’t make the developers fix the issue in the point-2, you can very well try the following for the point-4.

If the result of processing a POST would be equivalent to a representation of an existing resource, an origin server MAY redirect the user agent to that resource by sending a **303 (See Other)** response with the existing resource's identifier in the Location field.

[Refer the last paragraph under POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)

Comment: Thanks Deva for the input. In this case, there is no resource to redirect to. The resource exists in the 3rd parties system only. Thus there is no known identifier to reference it in that system because the POST response returned a 500 error when creating it.

Comment: In that case, can you make a get request to fetch the resource using any search APIs from the third party server?

Comment: I wish! unfortunately No :(